# No idea on how to create a function that determines if a number has an even digit within

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am learning to create functions. The whole program basically prints only the even digits of a number, but I need to create a function that, in case the number has no even digits, will print that it doesn't have any, but I have no idea on how to make the condition.
Thanks in advance.

So far this is the code without the function I need:

```
def imprimirPares (num):
    while num != 0:
        resultado = 0
        i = 1
        digito = num % 10
        if digito % 2 == 0:
            resultado += digito * i
            i *= 10
        num // 10
    return resultado

def ingresarEyS (num):
    print ("Nuevo numero con los valores pares de la cifra: ")
    num = ()
    print ("El nuevo numero es ",imprimirPares(num),".")
```

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly. Please fix it.

Comment: Is your requirement to print only the even position of a number, if so please try the following code: str(num)[::2]

Comment: I need it to print only the even digits, but I need a function that analizes if it has or not even numbers before making the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your already existing function this is fairly easy. One error you have made is that you do not assign the result of `num // 10` to `num` though.

```py
def has_even_digit(num):
    while num != 0:
        result = 0
        i = 1
        digit = num % 10
        if digit % 2 == 0:
            # even digit found
            return True
        else:
            result += digit * i
            i *= 10
            num = num // 10
    return False


print(has_even_digit(45))
print(has_even_digit(13))
print(has_even_digit(1579315))
print(has_even_digit(780278452))
```

Expected output:

```
True
False
False
True
```

### EDIT

As @Sash Sinha pointed out this solution only works for positive integers. Adjusting it for all integers is easy though using `num = abs(num)` before starting the while loop.

If you need this to work for `float` or `complex` a solution using `str` will be easier to implement and cleaner as demonstrated in @Sash Sinha's answer below.

Comment: This approach will only work for positive integers, e.g., try: `print(has_even_digit(-3333))` or  `print(has_even_digit(0.354))`.

Comment: Yes that's true. While adjusting it for negative numbers is simple by placing `num = abs(num)` at the top it will be a lot more complicated for `float` or `complex` with this approach. Your solution certainly is cleaner and works for any input. I just wanted to use what was already present as the starting point in the question.

Comment: I only need it for both positive and negative numbers, so it worked with that little correction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you are given a number, for example `"2345"`, and you are supposed to print `"2, 4"`.

1. Convert the number to string:
2. Create empty list to append even digits and Iterate:

> ```
> def evenDigits(num):
>   num = str(num)
>   evenNumbers = [] //empty list to store even numbers
>   for digit in num:
>     if digit % 2 == 0: //check if even digit
>       evenNumbers.append(digit)
>
> return evenNumbers //returns list with even numbers
>
> num = input("Give me a number!")
> result = evenDigits(num)
> print(*result, sep = ", ") //will print all even digits on same line.
> ```

Comment: I will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two separate functions for obtaining the digits and then checking if any digit is divisible by two.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from numbers import Number

def get_digits(num: Number) -> list[int]:
    return [int(ch) for ch in str(num) if ch.isdigit()]

def contains_even(digits: list[int]) -> bool:
    return any(d % 2 == 0 for d in digits)

def main() -> None:
    t = PrettyTable(['num', 'digits', 'contains_even'])
    t.align = 'l'
    for num in [11, -1230, -193.23, 23, 7.135, 0.354, -3333, complex(5.1, 4.5)]:
        digits = get_digits(num)
        t.add_row([num, digits, contains_even(digits)])
    print(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| num        | digits          | contains_even |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 11         | [1, 1]          | False         |
| -1230      | [1, 2, 3, 0]    | True          |
| -193.23    | [1, 9, 3, 2, 3] | True          |
| 23         | [2, 3]          | True          |
| 7.135      | [7, 1, 3, 5]    | False         |
| 0.354      | [0, 3, 5, 4]    | True          |
| -3333      | [3, 3, 3, 3]    | False         |
| (5.1+4.5j) | [5, 1, 4, 5]    | True          |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```